# If function seems to be bypassing clause 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that is erroring on occasion by letting in something I told it in the If statement to leave out. This function is being run over and over again during a while loop

```
def simulate_game(team1,rating1,team2,rating2):
    if team2 is "Bye":
        return team1
    else :
        matchup_arr = [team1,team2]
        pteam1 = 1/(1+10**((rating2-rating1)/250))
        pteam2 = 1- pteam1
        prob_arr = [pteam1,pteam2]
        winner = np.random.choice(matchup_arr,size=1,p=prob_arr)
    return winner
```

The formula is erroring when it is occasionally returning "Bye"
but I feel like I have written it in a way that if team2 is "Bye"... it gets kicked
But I am obviously missing something

Note: the file it is pulling from always lists a Bye in the Team2 spot

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `==`, not `is`, for equality comparisons:

```py
if team2 == "Bye":
```

`is` is for identity comparison, which you need very, very rarely.

As an aside, you can do this without Numpy (though I might have the `<` operator the wrong way around here :-) ) since the probabilities would sum up to 1, and `random.random()` returns a random value between 0 and 1:

```py
import random


def simulate_game(team1, rating1, team2, rating2):
    if team2 == "Bye":
        return team1

    pteam1 = 1 / (1 + 10 ** ((rating2 - rating1) / 250))
    return team1 if random.random() < pteam1 else team2
```

Comment: Thanks!. That solved the main problem and created another late on in the code. Is there any way for the "return team1" to return an array of one item ['team1']

Comment: `return [team1 (etc)]` - sorry for the brevity, on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

There's a not-so-obvious difference between `is` and `==`. `is` is for comparing identities, and `==` is for comparing objects to see if they're equal or not.

Example:

Let's do

```
> a = [1, 2, 3]
> b = a
```

If we ask the Python interpreter `a == b` we get `True`. If we ask the python interpreter `a is b`, we get `True` also, because these are pointing to the same object.

Now, let's do

```
> c = list(a)
> c
[1, 2, 3]
```

It looks identical, and, indeed, `a == c` is `True`, but `a is c` is `False` because `c` is a list and `a` is an array.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `==` instead of `is` in your `if` statement

Comment: This answer has already been said by the other answers.